# Count variable in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration, variable-assignment

I hope someone can help. I wrote the following code:

```
def minTransport(dict, max):
    sum = 0
    tempList = []
    counter = len(dict)
    tempCounter = len(dict)
    for item in get_partitions(dict):
        for list in item:
            for i in list:
                sum += dict[i]
            if sum <= limit:
                tempList.append(list)
                sum = 0
            else:
                sum = 0
                tempList = []
                break
        counter = len(tempList)
        if counter < tempCounter:
            result = tempList
            tempCounter = counter
            tempList = []
        else:
            tempList = []
    return result
```

`get_partitions` is a helper function that returns every single possible combination of the keys in the given dict. E.g. `dict={a:1, b:2, c:3}`, `for item in get_partitions(dict)` gets you:

`[[a, b, c]] or [[a,b], [c]] or [[a], [b,c]] or [[a,c],[b]] or[[a],[b],[c]]`

My program is supposed to iterate over those items, see if the sum of the values of the nested list <= max and if that's the case count all the nested lists in an item. In the above example `count` could have been `1 ([a,b,c]),2 (e.g. [a,b],[c]) or 3 ([a],[b],[c])`. The problem is that I don't know how to return the optimal solution meaning the item with the fewest amount of nested lists. If I set `counter = den(dict)` and `tempCounter = den(dict)`, after the first loop `tempCounter = 0` because the program will break (`sum > limit`) and the `counter = 0`. So that will always be the lowest value. If I try it differently I have the same problem (counter always den(dict)). 
It is basically 2 problems: 1. how can I make sure that the counter is just set to those items that are valid meaning `sum<=max` for all nested lists? And 2.: I sometimes get the Error Message `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment`. What does that mean and how is that possible if the program worked before and I don't change the positions of `result` in the code?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Let's keep it one question per post. [mcve] | [ask]

Comment: Your example doesn't explain what you want count to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Your second question... You should define `result` at the same level as your return statement. You sometimes get the `UnboundLocalError` message when your function never reaches the line where you define `result`.